# Can i mix these RAM memory?

Tags: motherboard, memory, pc

Can I use both of these RAM kits in the same computer?

- Corsair Vengeance DDR4 3600Mhz PC4-28800 16GB 2x8GB CL18
- Kingston fury beast pc4-28800 3600Mhz 16GB 2x8GB CL17

Answer (score 1):

You generally can (once proven by JayzTwoCents, cannot recreate vid link though), but it will run at slower speeds. If you run all sticks at JEDEC speed (2133Mhz CL14) it will defenetly work. You can try running it on the slowest XMP profile (3600Mhz CL18) and see if that works too, but I am not sure.

Comment: Don't forget to install the matching models in the same channel together too.